# Turning screen off when running in without window manager running

Tags: command-line, screen

Running an old laptop with Ubuntu 18.10 as a small server.

I have disabled the window manager to start at boot by setting:
`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` (since when I use the computer itself I don't need a window manager).

How do I turn the screen off when in console mode (outside of Gnome)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply close the laptop lid to keep dust off the keyboard and power off the screen.

As no desktop manager is running you need to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and change this line:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

to this:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Save the file and use `systemctl restart systemd-logind`